# Implementation of cache expiration with Future

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I'm trying to extend the cache implementation given in book Concurrency in Practice(by Brian Goetz).

I want to extend the cache such that if any entry is not accessed in 10 seconds then it should expire. i.e removed from cache.

For this I have extended Future and FutureTask as below

```
package examples.cache;

import java.util.concurrent.Future;

public interface FutureWithExpire<V> extends Future<V> {
    public boolean isResultExpired();
}
```

And

```
package examples.cache;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.FutureTask;

public class FutureTaskWithExpire<V> extends FutureTask<V> implements FutureWithExpire<V>{
    private final static long validPeriod = 10 * 1000;
    private long expirationTime;

    public FutureTaskWithExpire(Callable<V> callable) {
        super(callable);
    }

    @Override
    public V get() throws InterruptedException,ExecutionException{
        V v = super.get();
        expirationTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + validPeriod;
        return v;
    }

    public boolean isResultExpired(){
    if(isDone()){
        if(expirationTime < System.currentTimeMillis()){
        return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
    }
}
```

As seen above I'm overriding the the get method to calculate the expiration time.

And in the main cache Class i.e [Memorizer](http://jcip.net/listings/Memoizer.java) I will start a new thread that will periodically scan the entries and remove entries where `isResultExpired` returns true.

I just wanted to know if this implementation would work or there is some bug in my code?

Note I should also override [get with Timeout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html#get%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29). However, to keep it concise I have omitted that.

Comment: Instead of using `isResultExpired` you could just return `null` otherwise you can have a race condition where isExpiredResult is false but by the time you get it, it has expired.

Comment: In case you want expiration for some production code, and not just an exercise, you can evaluate relying on JVM for expiration of cached items, using `WeakHashMap` class.

Answer (score 1):

And Ofcourse expirationTime should be volatile

Answer (score 0):

Why is this code:

```
 expirationTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + validPeriod;
```

in the get method? Seems to me it should be in the constructor, otherwise it could be invalidated way too fast. Suppose that you created the  **FutureTaskWithExpire** instance and some other Thread, the one that is suppose to invalidate entries calls the isResultExpired method, expiration time will be actually zero and thus the entry will be invalidated, even though it still had time live.

Also I think that the calls to get and isExpired should be synchronized on a ReentrantLock for example, because you do not want some Thread to invalidate your entry, while in another Thread you are trying to give that entry.

Comment: That's why I'm using isDone() - so the method will return true only if the task is completed but yes agree that the 2 methods should be synchronized.